# How can I hide/remove the button at bottom right that shows the desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

How can I hide/remove the button at bottom right that shows the desktop in  Windows 10?

I am referring to this (orange rectangle):

[image]

Comment: @FrankThomas Thanks.  some solutions may be specific to Windows 7 or 10 though

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - In this case there isn't a difference.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It seems perfectly valid. It's the top hit for Google search "remove button bottom right windows 10".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) and  check the following option:

[image]